# Convert SQL LIKE expression to regex with c++ or Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt

I have query like this:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM T
WHERE ( a LIKE 'f%' OR b LIKE 'f%' OR c LIKE 'f%' )
```

Of course the original query is more complicated with more complex filter.

I need to determine in which field was matching `a, b or c`
Based on that I use Qt a can compare result with regex.

But how to convert expression in `LIKE` to regex.

In [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/convert-sql-like-to-regex) article is present a partial solution. But may be exists more holistic example?

PS: (Answer for questions in comments).

- I deal with different DBMS (PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL) not all of them has build-in regex support
- I want to find matching like:

  const QString valueA( GetValueFromQuery() );
  if( valueA.contains( QRegExp( _CONVERTED_EXPRESSION_ )) {}
- In the linked post a handmade solution described. I want to find other proven solutions.

Comment: Regexp is product specific SQL functionality. Tag dbms used!

Comment: Why do you want a RegEx, you still need to apply it to all three columns? And how do you want to indicate *which field was matching*?

Comment: Why do you want to perform the regex matching at C++-level whereas you may replace your `LIKE` operation by a regex matching ? But that is DB-specific so you need to tag the DBMS you use, unless you really want to filter results at C++-level.

Comment: If I understand, you are simply asking the regex equivalent of SQL's `f%` ? It means start with f then can have zero ore more characters, so the regex equivalent is `^f.*`

Comment: I have added more info to the original question. And of course, the filter can be any, not only 'f%'.

Comment: Based on your edit: If you can do the same using `LIKE` this is preferred over more complicated RegExs in a UDF. Simply use `case when a like 'f%' then 1 else 0 end as a_matched` to know which column matched, if you don't want to repeat he `LIKE` you can easily move it to a Derived Table and the apply `WHERE a_matched = 1`

Comment: @dnoeth - in general this is a good suggestion, but in my case it will lead to very big queries, part of which should be generated automatically, and will lead to many bugs. I prefer to use regex, just to determine matching in the result.

Comment: Adding one more level of Derived Tables leads to big queries? `SELECT ... FROM (smaller query) dt WHERE a_mached=1 or b_mached=1 or c_mached=1`

Comment: @dnoeth - can you provide me an example how I can to get both - result value, and flag is this result is matched to pattern. You can use example query from the query. Because I really don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

While I still prefer the solution by adding the results of the `LIKE` parts to the result set this might do what you want.

This code still might contain errors and is not optimized:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string& replace_all(std::string& str, const std::string& old_value, const std::string& new_value)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    while ((pos = str.find(old_value, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        str.replace(pos, old_value.size(), new_value);
        pos += new_value.size() - old_value.size() + 1;
    }
    return str;
}

std::map<std::string, std::string> extractCharacterRanges(std::string& str)
{
    std::map<std::string, std::string> ranges;

    int rangeID = 0;
    std::string::size_type startPos = 0;
    std::string::size_type endPos = 0;

    while ((startPos = str.find("[", startPos)) != std::string::npos && (endPos = str.find("]", startPos + 1)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "[[" << rangeID << "]]";
        std::string chars = str.substr(startPos + 1, endPos - startPos - 1);
        str.replace(startPos, chars.size() + 2, ss.str());
        rangeID++;
        startPos += ss.str().size();

        replace_all(chars, "[", "\\[");
        replace_all(chars, "]", "\\]");
        ranges[ss.str()] = "[" + chars + "]";
    }

    int open = 0;
    std::string::size_type searchPos = 0;
    startPos = 0; endPos = 0;
    do
    {
        startPos = str.find("[", searchPos);
        endPos = str.find("]", searchPos);

        if (startPos == std::string::npos && endPos == std::string::npos)
            break;

        if (startPos < endPos || endPos == std::string::npos)
        {
            open++;
            searchPos = startPos + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (open <= 0)
            {
                str.replace(endPos, 1, "\\]");
                searchPos = endPos + 2;
            }
            else
            {
                open--;
                searchPos = endPos + 1;
            }
        }
    } while (searchPos < str.size());
    return ranges;
}


std::string sqllike_to_regex(std::string sqllike)
{
    replace_all(sqllike, ".", "\\.");
    replace_all(sqllike, "^", "\\^");
    replace_all(sqllike, "$", "\\$");
    replace_all(sqllike, "+", "\\+");
    replace_all(sqllike, "?", "\\?");
    replace_all(sqllike, "(", "\\(");
    replace_all(sqllike, ")", "\\)");
    replace_all(sqllike, "{", "\\{");
    replace_all(sqllike, "}", "\\}");
    replace_all(sqllike, "\\", "\\\\");
    replace_all(sqllike, "|", "\\|");
    replace_all(sqllike, ".", "\\.");
    replace_all(sqllike, "*", "\\*");
    std::map<std::string, std::string> ranges = extractCharacterRanges(sqllike); //Escapes [ and ] where necessary
    replace_all(sqllike, "%", ".*");
    replace_all(sqllike, "_", ".");
    for (auto& range : ranges)
    {
        replace_all(sqllike, range.first, range.second);
    }
    return "^" + sqllike + "$";
}


int main() {
    std::cout << sqllike_to_regex("f%") << std::endl;//^f.*$
    std::cout << sqllike_to_regex("[A-Z]%") << std::endl;//^[A-Z].*$
    std::cout << sqllike_to_regex("[[A-Z][asd]]") << std::endl;//^[\[A - Z][asd]\]$
    std::cout << sqllike_to_regex("a]a") << std::endl;//^a\]a$
    std::cout << sqllike_to_regex("[%] [[] ] % [_] _") << std::endl;//^[%] [\[] \] .* [_] .$
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either repeat the LIKE to get a match flag or wrap it into a Derived Table:

```
SELECT a, b, c, 
   case when a LIKE 'f%' then 1 else 0 end as a_matched,
   case when b LIKE 'f%' then 1 else 0 end as b_matched,
   case when c LIKE 'f%' then 1 else 0 end as b_matched
FROM T
WHERE ( a LIKE 'f%' OR b LIKE 'f%' OR c LIKE 'f%' )
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT a, b, c, 
      case when a LIKE 'f%' then 1 else 0 end as a_matched,
      case when b LIKE 'f%' then 1 else 0 end as b_matched,
      case when c LIKE 'f%' then 1 else 0 end as b_matched
   FROM T
 ) dt
WHERE ( a_matched OR b_matched OR c_matched )
```

Both should be optimized the same way, of course you better check the actual plans.